# Javascript encryption for JSON object

Tags: jquery, encryption, serialization, cryptography

I have a JSON object that I generate from serializeArray on a form which I would like to encrypt. The application I am working on is intended to run only as a local file. What would be the best option for encrypting the data?

Comment: Why the need to encrypt form data? for transport, storage? What do you plan to achieve?

Comment: It's mainly just due to the sensitivity of the data just so that we can inform the user that reasonable precautions have been taken to protect the user input, while acknowledging that it's not completely foolproof due to the inherent limitations of using javascript/browser.

Comment: If the data is transported using HTTPS no additional encryption is necessary.

Comment: The file will be run as a local file so it won't be over HTTPS. However, since localstorage is stored as plain text, the users want the stored data to be encrypted so that it won't be so easily accessed by someone else, even if the solution won't be ideal given that it's client-based rather than server-based

Comment: I am writing an app that also needs to "obfuscate" its config files which I do using the built-in JS functions `btoa` and `atob` to convert to and from base64. This is no encryption but will prevent most users from messing up with the files and does not require an external library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just an idea. Use cryptoJS as suggested in this sample:

```js
var secret = "My Secret Passphrase";
var plainText = "the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secret);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, secret);

document.getElementById("m1").innerHTML = encrypted;
document.getElementById("m2").innerHTML = decrypted;
document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<label>encrypted</label>
<div id="m1"></div>
<br>
<label>decrypted</label>
<div id="m2"></div>
<br>
<label>Original message</label>
<div id="m3"></div>
```

and encrypt all your data before placing it in localstorage.
I do not see how you can implement this beside asking some sort of password from the user.

Comment: Is CryptoJS still under development? Should I consider WebCrypto instead?

Comment: Use what you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try out this. This worked out for me well for dynamic json data as well as normal text.

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("93wj660t8fok9jws");
// Please parse the your secret key
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8));

function encrypt(plainText) {
     return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
plainText, key,{ iv: iv,padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC }).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}
function decrypt(encryptedText) {  
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create(
    {
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedText)
    });
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, { iv: iv,
                               padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                               mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
                              }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
    var start = new Date().getTime();
var encrypted = encrypt(
'{\"name\": \"Sushant\", \"loves\": \"cats\"}'
);
    var end = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end - start);
document.getElementById('enc').innerHTML = encrypted;
document.getElementById('dec').innerHTML = decrypt(encrypted);
```